# Count total words from text file serperated by "," (comma) in batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, count

I have a comma d eliminated text file (names.txt) in which there is a string for ex Mike,Joe,Kelly.

I need to get total count of strings like : total name : 3 and store this result in a variable and call it further in my batch script. I googled a lot but not getting proper code.

It would be really great if I can get an answer from this expert group. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: which language?

Comment: @Dr.Geek: `Batch` according to the tags.

Comment: yes @Stephan that's correct. It's Batch scripting.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand correctly, your textfile has only one line.

```
@echo off
<t.txt set /p line=
set a=0
for %%a in (%line%) do set /a a+=1
echo %a%
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, it looks too good. Yes my text file contains single line which is , deliminated. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: note: this will fail with something like `Mike,Mary Sue,Kelly` which will give you a count of `4` (spaces, tabs and commas are standard delimters)

Answer (score -1):

A simple way, just 1 command line: ( name count is just the return value `%ERRORLEVEL%` )

`msr -p your-file.txt -t "," -o "\n" -PAC | msr -t "\w+"`

Store to a variable:

- Name count ? `set /a NameCount=%ERRORLEVEL%`
- Full string ? `set "ResultText=Total name : %ERRORLEVEL%"`

Additionally, if you want to hide output of the command, redirect output to nothing by `>nul` :

`msr -p your-file.txt -t "," -o "\n" -PAC | msr -t "\w+" >nul`

`msr.exe` / `msr-Win32.exe` is a single portable exe tool for file processing with cross platform versions. see `tools` directory in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr . You can also see: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html

Comment: Hi , thanks for your suggestion but I need to use code for servers hence I can not use any third party tool

Comment: Oh, if your file is just one line,  then **Stephan** gave a good answer below.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Stephan's code was work like a charm.